# Printing result in RDP is not clear

Tags: remote-desktop

I need some help about redirected printer in Remote desktop Connection. I wonder why does the printing result of my client unit is not clear. I thought the problem is in the printer but when I tried to print test locally, printing result is OK and clear.

Server and Client is both windows 7 ultimate..

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "is not clear"?

Comment: Please add a question in your question :)